# Is there really no simple way to check if variable is integer (whether in string or int type)?

Tags: php

I need to check whether a variable contains integers only, and since PHP doesn't really care if numbers are represented in STRING type or not, I don't care either.

But when I use `is_int()` it returns false for `'1'` and when I use `ctype_digit()` it returns false for `1`!

And `is_numeric()`, while accepting both string and float, accepts decimal numbers too.

I'm looking for a function that works like `is_numeric()` but doesn't accept decimals.

```
$var[] = 2;
$var[] = '2';

foreach($var as $key => $val){
    if( ! is_int($val) && ! ctype_digit($val)) // <-- Any single function equivalent to these two checks?
        return false;
}
```

P.S. I'm not lazy, but this has been bothering me for a long time that `is_numeric()` accepts string format numbers, but `is_int()` doesn't!

Comment: Note from the dupe that `ctype_digit((string)1)` will produce true.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a regex match to check if variable contains only integers using [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function

```
<?php

if(preg_match('/^\d+$/',$x) === 1){
  // your code goes here
}
```